# Check the content of other cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a really stupid question, as you can see in the image below i want to check the content of the first 3 columns on the left, if the content is ok just show ok in the fourth column. 
The only conditions are those shown in the first 2 rows, so a not empty cell in the first column and the other two empty or the opposite, two on the right not empty and the first column empty. How can I do it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Wvb.png)

Comment: Can you refrase your question to make it clearer what the conditions are. You are talking about rows at the moment, plus from the picture you posted it is definately not clear what values/columns you are checking. Currently its just a picture of a few headers (in Spanish?)

Comment: You can use a combination of if() with and() but without example data...

Comment: sorry, I've uploaded the wrong picture, now you can see the good one showing the table

Comment: I've just uploaded the right picture, sorry, @JvdV it is italian :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more 'traditional' approach...suppose your data starts in the first row, in Cell `D1` enter the following and drag it down

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1<>"",SUMPRODUCT(--ISBLANK(B1:C1))=2),AND(ISBLANK(A1),SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISBLANK(B1:C1)))=2)),"OK","NOT OK")
```

> the logic is straight forward, use **AND** to validate the two valid combinations and use **OR** to return `TRUE` for any match and use **IF** to return the desired outcome if the condition is met.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick help, and sorry for my bad explanation. @terry your solution worked flawlessly

Answer (score 1):

Assume your data put in A1:C3

In D1, copied down :

```
=IF(OR(BIN2DEC(1-ISBLANK(A1)&1-ISBLANK(B1)&1-ISBLANK(C1))={3,4}),"OK","CHECK")
```

Comment: never seen anything like this before... amazing!